# How to create folders in website running in IIS 7 at runtime with all permissions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke

My app is supposed to create a structure of folders during execution in which it will create, store and process the files generated at run time. This system has been tested in a desktop application and works fine. Now I am trying to use this in a C# asp.net webforms DNN project but it does not as per expectation.

When I debug the project the directories are created at the following location the reasons for which I do not understand(but the application executes fine):

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\
```

When I run the same application through localhost environment(IIS 7, .NET 4.0, Integrated Pipeline mode), the following exception is thrown:

> A critical error has occurred. Access to the path
>   'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Processing\' is denied.

The "Processing" directory is not created either as per verified application logic.

I want this folder structure to get created in the bin folder of my application executing in IIS. I created the folder structure manually at the required location by creating virtual directories structure as per requirement in the bin folder of the application but that did not help either.

So my question is:

- Please can someone clarify how and where the directories and files created by a website are supposed to get saved when hosted in IIS.
- What are the steps that I will need to follow to ensure the files and directories are created in the bin folder of my app executing in IIS 7 with all the rights.
- Are there any code modifications that I will have to make in order for this to happen.

Any links and answers pointing me to the write direction are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your web server (IIS or local dev server) is just going to save to its working directory.  If you want to save to a specific path, get the physical path corresponding to your application using *[MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.mappath.aspx)* (or *[Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)*).  For example:

```
string path = MapPath("~/bin");
```

You'll also need to make sure that the account that IIS is running under has read/write permissions to the directory you need to write to.  That means going into your server and modifying the permissions on the folder.  To find the user account, you'll have to go to the *Advanced Settings* under your application pool and check what is set for *Identity*.

Comment: That was exactly the problem - I was using Environment.CurrentDirectory to get the location in the desktop app which returned the working directory for the web server in the web app. Your solution fixed it perfectly. Thanks!